# Why the disabled button is not getting enabled using the jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net button rendered as

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_tpAllocate_btnNewInvoiceFalse
```

this is the ID.

Now in jquery in console of inspect element, I am writing.

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_tpAllocate_btnNewInvoiceFalse").prop("disabled",false)
```

Not working.

then I tried

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_tpAllocate_btnNewInvoiceFalse").removeAttr('disabled');
```

but not working.

Comment: You've targeted a wrong window in the console?

Comment: same window .. but not working